# Submitted URI too large! The length of the requested URL exceeds the capacity limit for this server. The request cannot be processed

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

"Submitted URI too large!

The length of the requested URL exceeds the capacity limit for this server. The request cannot be processed."

Thanks in advance!
Here is the php code

```
if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
```

}

?>
NOTE: I DID ALL THE PROCESS VIA DREAMWEAVER AND IT INSERT THE PHP CODE ITSELF.

Comment: What does the URI look like?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact URL, I suppose you have submitted a large form with GET request. There are some limits for this, and the exact character limits are depending on browser and the webserver you are using.

You should consider using POST requests.

Comment: Or you could add the data to the session or some kind of data store if a POST request isn't feasible